# Error: spawn UNKNOWN during npx create-react-app run

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

This is the error message from the command prompt.

My node version - v16.16.0.

My npm version - 8.15.1.

I use Windows 11.

I tried running this command in powershell, tried clearing npm cache and running cmd as an admin. But the result is the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
V:\programming\geek_brains\first_quarter\react>npx create-react-app my-app
    npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Creating a new React app in V:\programming\geek_brains\first_quarter\react\my-app.

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
    at C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from V:\programming\geek_brains\first_quarter\react
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install -g create-react-app`

> this command is used for install react globally.

2. `npx create-react-app my-app`

> this command create new react project.

Comment: add some description of what you mean to say ?

Comment: `npm install -g create-react-app` this command is used for install react globally.
`npx create-react-app my-app` this command create new react project.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still occurs.